# Didn't launch application on Moto Xoom tablet

Tags: android, xamarin, motorola-droid

I am developing on android application, and it works on every phone and tablet only on Moto Xoom (10 inch tab) that didn't open, only white screen is show.

AndroidManifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionName="2.4" package="lionbridge.tms.notification" android:versionCode="5">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application android:label="TMS Tasks" android:icon="@drawable/Icon"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Splashscreen.cs

```
namespace Mobile.UI.Droid
{
    [Activity(
        Label = "Mobile Tasks"
        , MainLauncher = true
        , Icon = "@drawable/icon"
        , Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoTitle"
        //, Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash"// Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        , NoHistory = true)]
        // ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class SplashScreen : MvxSplashScreenActivity
    {
        public SplashScreen()
            : base(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnCreate(Android.OS.Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            if (IsTablet(this))
            {
            }
            else
            {
                RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
            }
        }

        #region Check android device/Tablet
        public static bool IsTablet(Context context)
        {
            return (context.Resources.Configuration.ScreenLayout & ScreenLayout.SizeMask) >= ScreenLayout.SizeLarge;
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: The manifest by itself is definitely not enough information, post some C# code or a logcat dump of the startup. Impossible to diagnose without more information.

Comment: Much better thanks :) If you can also get a logcat capture that would help as well.

Comment: Actually matthewrdev my device (Moto Xoom) is not detect in my pc so I cant get logcat files:(